# Oracle DB and SecureString

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g, securestring

I am currently storing the user password in a `SecureString`. Which is also kept around in case the connection to the DB resets.

My problem is, I'm trying to pass this password to an `OracleParamater`, but I'm not sure if it supports it or not.

Does Oracle's `Oracle.DataAccess` dll support `SecureString` or `BStr`? Since If I have to convert it to a string then that would kinda defeat the purpose of `SecureString`.

--- EDIT

I know that `SecureString` is about reducing the attack surface by keeping as few copies of the password around unencrypted as possible. The problem is at some point you ofcourse have to decrypt the password to use it. If I could pass a `char[]` or a `BStr` or the secure string itself in an `OracleParameter` then I could clear it after the call returns. But If I have to create a string in order to pass it to Oracle, then I've just created a new immutable copy of the password. So I'm not really sure I gained much then.

Comment: SecureString is an "in-memory" concept... ADO.NET has nothing to do with it... IF you are concerned about security "over the wire" then use an encrypted connection and/or a certificate-based approach...

Comment: I am Not concered about security "over the wire" and that was not the intention of the question. I'll append the question to clarify

Comment: ok... that is more clear now... see my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - AFAIK what you ask is not supported...

BUT even if it were supported the security issue would remain since the Oracle driver used (OCI) is native and does not know anything about `SecureString` thus it will handle the value internally without encryption which in turn means that this value can end up for example unencrypted in the swap file...

It would be a bit more secure if what you ask were supported on the .NET side of things but merely so...

IF you really need that level of security I would recommend redesigning that part of your software to use encrypted values in a way that the server-side (Oracle DB) of things does not require "plain text" but works with the encrypted values...

Comment: I was afraid of this. I don't really need this level of security, but I figured precisely because the Oracle driver is native, it probably uses a (w_)char* for strings. I could still zero that if it would take the unmanaged string as input. But it's a shame that almost no API support SecureString. Thanks for confirming though.

Answer (score 0):

[SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) is an in-memory holder of your private information.

The reason it was implemented, is that if you use simple `string` for holding user private information, even after you no more reference that object and it was already garbage collected, it's potentially possible that hacker-code by executing dump of your process memory could still access a data available in that memory location, so access the private information.

In case of `SecureString`, instead, that location will be erased so even on memory dump you will not see anything related to the string used in your code.

As suggested by Yahia, if you concern about *connection security* or *data transmisson security*, use secure connection for that purpose.

Comment: This isn't at all about connection security. I'm quite aware that taht's a different subject. I'm refering to the in-memory security here. I know that SecureString is about reducing the attack surface. But If I have to convert the SecureString into a string to connect to Oracle, then I just exposed the plaintext password as a string. Over which I no longer have any control in terms of when it's garbage collected

Comment: @Phyx: well, if you care about in-memory security, by using SecureString you already at a good point.

Comment: @Phyx: may be I undesrtood your **real** concern. The thing is that in the moment when you convert SecureString to String, you loose any benefit of the protection. So the code becomes non protected. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's almost it. I'm aware of that. I'm actually asking if there's a way to prevent to convert it to the immutable .NET string value when making the connection. But it seems the Oracle API just doesn't support that unfortunately :(

Comment: @Phyx: I'm not sure, but I *think* it uses COM to interact with it, but SecureString (according to the MSDN) "The SecureString class and its members are not visible to COM". So.. :(