# Oracle Connect String found in Clear in .NET memory dump

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, memory, odp.net

Our C# .NET applications are currently undergoing the dreaded PCI audit and they have raised the following issue. They were able to find the Oracle connect string in clear in a memory dump. We use ODP.NET Managed Data Access lib. Since OracleConnection requires the connection string to be passed as a string variable, there is no way I know of that can address this. We have looked into using SecureString (ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467112/oracle-db-and-securestring?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) issue) but it is incompatible with the Oracle API.

Storing it encrypted in app.config or similar file is no help since eventually we need to decrypt and submit it in clear, which brings us back to the original point of it being found in clear in memory.

Honestly, I am surprised that Oracle does not already have something in place for this being the giant they are, so we feel like we are missing something obvious. So I am here to ask the community if there is something that can remove the password or whole db connect string from memory or if we can submit the connect string itself as encrypted for Oracle to decrypt.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you use Windows Authentication to connect to oracle?

Comment: Which part of the PCI audit requires that the database password not be in clear text in a memory dump? Where did the memory dump come from (did they create it as part of the audit, or was it just lying around)?

Comment: It would also be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].